# How do I store session information in a multipage form and send the information to mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I've been running into a roadblock for the longest time on a project I've been working on. I have a multipage form where I collect data from an end-user over multiple pages and submit them into my database at the end, but there's no data showing up when I check the tables.

The form for page 1 looks like

```
<?php
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Form 2 looks like so..

```
<?php
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}
//Fetching values from form 1
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
 }

?>
```

Form 3 looks like

```
<?php
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}
//Fetching values from form 2
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
 }

?>
```

The completion form looks like

```
<?php
 code.
session_start();
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit();
}
//Fetching values from form 3
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $_SESSION['post'][$key] = $value;
 }

 extract($_SESSION['post']); // Function to extract array.

 $DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
 $DATABASE_USER = 'root';
 $DATABASE_PASS = '';
 $DATABASE_NAME = 'qraccounts';
 // Try and connect using the info above.
 $con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     // If there is an error with the connection, stop the script and display the error.
     die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO logindata (database_value1, database_value2, database_value3, database_value4, database_value5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {
 $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $_POST['value1'], $_POST['value2'], $_POST['value3'], $_POST['value4'], $_POST['value5']);
 $stmt->execute();
}

?>
```

Does anything jump out at you that would prevent me from storing user data in my SQL table over multiple sessions?

My database is a single table with id, email, password (hashed), database_value1, database_value2, database_value3, database_value4, database_value5. Do I need to store data from way earlier like in the registration page?

Comment: In your database query you should use `$_SESSION['post']['value1']` rather than `$_POST['value1']`. And also remove that line with `extract(...)`, as it does not do what you expect.

Comment: What's going on with this question, if I may ask? There's an answer below. Have you tried it? Did it solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already passing values to session.
you can use sessions like :

```
$_SESSION['database_value1'];
$_SESSION['database_value2'];
```